# Is it possible to pass one extra bit of information from Socket.Connect to Socket.Accept?

Tags: sockets, tcp

In a client - server type system, it would simplify my server code somewhat if the client could indicate if it was trying to make a new connection or was attempting to reconnect after a connection failure.

I realize that in reality a new connection is a new connection, period. But by passing this one extra bit of information it would simplify my server's handling of the situation - which threads and data areas can be reused and which threads should be killed, etc. By not having this one extra bit the server is forced to assume reconnection when possible, and then reassess that assumption when the first message arrives, where the client indicates whether it is attempting to revive the previous conversation or wishes to start a completely new relationship.

I'm guessing the answer is no, but any suggestions are welcome.

By the way, the client is an Android program and the server is .Net Windows.

Comment: Look into `OutOfBoundData`, might be of some help

Comment: @AnshDavid: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd never even heard of out-of-band data before. But from the little bit I've now read about it, I don't think it comes through as part of the connect/accept handshake, which is where I would like to receive the extra flag bit.

Comment: Ok. Is this the only way you want to come about this problem or are u open for some suggestions?

Comment: @AnshDavid: Always open to suggestions. :-)  I've even considered having two sockets listening for new connections instead of one, one socket for real new connections and one for reconnection connections. But that would be just too kludgy.

Comment: Was looking up the TCP functional procedure. If not sending an extra packet ... maybe u can tweek the packet itself. Then write a diff code on the server side that would recognize the unique packet. Particularly i was looking into the SYN SYN_ACT ACK flags

Comment: @AnshDavid: Thanks for your suggestions. But the things you're suggesting seem to imply that I'd have to modify Android and/or Java at the Socket.Connect end, and Windows and/or .Net at the Socket.Accept end, and I'm not willing to get into that. Anyway, I've now rewritten my program so the .Net end always assumes reconnection attempt if that's a possibility, and the Android end indicates in its first message if it is trying to revive an existing "connection" or wants a "brand new" connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm guessing the answer is no

The answer is no.

> but any suggestions are welcome.

*Either* (a) it should be obvious from your application protocol whether the client is connecting or reconnecting, *or* (b) it shouldn't make any difference which it is. Much more usually, (b).

Comment: Thanks for your definitive answer. As you imply, there may well be something wrong with my whole protocol. I'm trying to wedge a reconnect-after-failure facility into a protocol that was never intended for that, PC-to-PC connections being stable enough that a communications failure previously was considered final. Someday I may get a chance to redesign the whole thing, but not now. Thanks again.